# Performance monitoring on a Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, performance-testing, database-performance, toad

I'm currently using TOAD and oracle 11g. My team is moving to a production DB and server soon. My question is what are the best practices/ methods for developing tools to perform health checks and monitoring tools?

Answer (score 1):

Database control is included with your Oracle install and is free.  Enterprise Manager has an Express edition and then there is the version with the most features OEM Grid or 12c Cloud Control depending on what version you want.  Some of this strays into Oracle licencing for which you should contact your oracle rep. 
More details can be found [here](http://bijoos.com/oraclenotes/2014/404).

At the very minimum you need a library of scripts that can check tablespaces, parameters, memory usage and so on for the day I hope you never have when you have to do it the hard way without a GUI.

For day to day and automated monitoring I have found the Oracle tools to be quite satisfactory.  Toad is expensive and must be installed on every client.  It is great for one or two people to monitor hot spot performance issues but if you want to get an email when there is a locking session or low disk space OEM works well.